cocycle condition of stratification
Let $R,A$ be commutative rings, and $A$ is an $R$-algebra, $E$ is an $A$-module, $P = A \otimes_R A$, and $P^n$ is the $n$-th infinitesimal neighborhood of $A$ in $P$. A stratification on $E$ is a collection of isomorphisms $\epsilon_n \colon P^n \otimes_A E \to E \otimes_A P^n$ such that (1) $\epsilon_n$ is $P^n$-linear. (2) $\epsilon_n$ and $\epsilon_m$ are compatible, and $\epsilon_0$ is the identity. Moreover, there is a cocycle condition. Let $P^n(2)$ be the $n$-th infinitesimal neighborhood of $A$ in $A\otimes_R A\otimes_R A$, and $p_{ij}$ is the map to the $i,j$ factor. Then for all $n$,
\begin{equation}
p_{12}^* (\epsilon_n) \circ p_{23}^*(\epsilon_n) = p_{13}^*(\epsilon_n)
\end{equation}
Of course this is like the usual cocycle condition in descent data. It is said in Berthlot & Ogus Notes on Crystalline Cohomology, 2.10.4b) that such cocycle condition is equivalent to $\delta^{m,n*}(\epsilon_{m+n}) = (\epsilon_m \otimes \mathrm{id}) \circ (\mathrm{id}\otimes \epsilon_n)$ as maps
\begin{equation}
P^m \otimes P^n \otimes E \to P^m \otimes E \otimes P^n \to E \otimes P^m \otimes P^n,
\end{equation}
where $\delta^{m,n} \colon P^{n+m} \to P^m \otimes P^n, a \otimes b \mapsto a \otimes 1 \otimes 1 \otimes b$.
However, I can't see why these two cocycle conditions are equivalent. I have only a rough idea on how the first cocycle condition implies the second, but not vice versa.
Edit: I think I know what is going on here. There are three natural maps
$P^{n+m} \to P^{n+m}(2) \to P^n\otimes P^m$, they are $p_{12},p_{23},p_{13} = \delta$. Also the identity induces natural map $P^n \otimes P^n \to P^n(2)$. Just by change of rings we see two cocycle conditions are equivalent.

I think the point is that you can deduce the second condition for all $(m,n)$ just from knowing it for $(n,n)$ for all $n$. The other piece of the puzzle is on the preceding paragraph: $p_{13}^*$ is identified with $\delta: P \to P \otimes P$.

@JoshuaMundinger Yes, but my problem is to deduce first cocycle condition from the second one.

Oh I think I know what is going on. To deduce the first from the second, one may base change from $P^n \otimes_A P^n$ to $P^n(2)$. But I need to check the details.
